# java DAO update query failure

Tags: java, postgresql, dao, jdbi

I am trying to write DAO method to update value in postgres table "accounts" with just two columns:
"id" string 
"balance" int

```
public Account setAccountBalance(String id, Integer balance) {
    Handle h = dbi.open();

    try{
        return h.createQuery("UPDATE accounts SET balance=" + balance.intValue() +
                            " WHERE id=\'" + id +"\';")
                .mapTo(Account.class)
                .first();
    } finally {
        h.close();
    }
}
```

But on execute I see the following exception:
org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.NoResultsException: Query did not have a result set, perhaps you meant update? [statement:"UPDATE accounts SET balance=20 WHERE id='1';", located:"UPDATE accounts SET balance=20 WHERE id='1';", rewritten:"UPDATE accounts SET balance=20 WHERE id='1';", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{id:'1'}, finder:[]}]

Any idea if the problem is in query syntax, or use of DAO?

Comment: You could try removing the semicolon from the query string. And you should definitely be using prepared statements instead of string concatenation of query parameters.

Comment: Also, you have an UPDATE SQL which usually (depending on JDBC driver) doesn't have a result set. You're probably using the wrong API method (`createQuery()`) for the update.

Comment: Also, learn about prepared statements. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, and will fail if an ID eve contains a quote.

Comment: You're probably using the wrong API method (createQuery()) for the update. – Mick Mnemonic That makes sense... What method should I use?

Comment: No idea, really because I don't know the API you're using. A quick Google suggests [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/jdbi2/), and there is an `execute()` method that probably works. The link has examples of prepared statements (questionmarks in the SQL) so you can switch to using them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/jdbi2/). According to the documentation, SQL UPDATEs can be performed through `Handle.execute()`, as follows:

```
h.execute("UPDATE accounts SET balance=? WHERE id=?", balance.intValue(), id);
```

But the execute method doesn't return a result set and therefore cannot be used for creating an `Account` object. You would need to issue a separate query for doing that, maybe something like

```
return h.createQuery("SELECT id, balance FROM accounts WHERE id = :id")
            .bind("id", id)
            .mapTo(Account.class)
            .first();
```

Comment: Would that work in the case of multiple clients and one database?

Comment: Yes, but if you would be building e.g. a real banking application, you'd need to consider the bigger picture regarding transactions and [isolation levels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Isolation_levels). For example, setting the account balance would need to be an operation that prevents other clients from simultaneously modifying the same account. One way to achieve this is to acquire a _lock_ to the table row prior to the update, e.g. via the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` SQL clause. But this topic is out of scope of your original question.